# Why isn't Excel updating formulas automatically?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Excel is not working correctly for me. When I change the input of a formula, the output is not automatically updated. Could this be due to a virus? How do I get Excel to update formulas automatically again?

Comment: No, it's not a virus.

Answer (score 9):

If it is, this sounds like one of the most annoying viruses in the world!

No, most likely you simply have calculations set to Manual, or something else similar such as an add-in, macro or extension e.t.c. that is interfering with the normal operations of Excel.

To check for the easiest one, go to `Formulas` > `Calculation Options`, and make sure it is set to `Automatic`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and when I changed the format to "number" the cells started calculating and updating correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I had trouble getting formulas to update, until I realised some cells had formatting applied (formatted as Text I think?). Fixed by right-clicking on the cell, selecting `Format Cells...` and choosing `General` under Category.

Comment: That is my goto trick as well. I still don't know why excel behaves this way and in my point of view it is definitely a bug.

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be a bug.  I've had the same issue since we recently "upgraded" to Office 2013.

I have formulas linking to other tabs in the same workbook.  Some of them are not even formulas - they just "=" the number from the other tab.  Even these simple links don't refresh with F9.

I've found that if you click in the formula bar when in the source cell, and hit enter, it refreshes the cell which is linked to it.  To do this on a grand scale, I do a Find "=" & Replace with "=" for the whole workbook.  This forces recalculation of all cells.

Hope this helps...