# WHY are my formulas suddenly not calculating on Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I understand how to fix the issue (switch calculating option from manual to automatic) but I am curious as to WHY it went to manual. Could it be some kind of update? I have been using these spreadsheets for a long time, and suddenly today this issue came to be. I'm using Microsoft office 2007.

Its only certain files, and they are stored in a network drive. We have not installed any updates recently to our computers, and only a handful of people are experiencing these issues.

Comment: Would be nice to have some details. There is no way for us to guess why. Please [Edit] your question with some more details like; Is it all of your workbooks or only select few? Are these files stored on a network drive? Have any updates been installed recently?

Comment: Sorry! I realized how vague it was shortly after! Its only certain files, and they are stored in a network drive. We have not installed any updates recently to our computers, and only a handful of people are experiencing these issues.

Comment: No problem. Just click [edit] under the question to be able to update it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why isn't Excel updating formulas automatically?](http://superuser.com/questions/496611/why-isnt-excel-updating-formulas-automatically)

Comment: It's not a duplicate. OP explicitly said that he knows how to fix it, but wants to know *why*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since these files are shared on a network drive, it is highly likely someone else who is using the files is saving them with auto-calculation turned off. This is evident because you say its only certain files. This indicates those are the files that person has saved in that fashion.

To verify this, open one of the problem files, switch it back to auto-calculation and save it again. Open it again. If the changes stay, then you need to find out who is saving them that way.

Comment: Other than a user switching it without realizing it, (which is very possible) can you think of any reason the auto-calculation would be set to manual?

Comment: Usually because there is large number of calculations that slow down the workbook too much.

Comment: Someone may turn it off to avoid errors while working with complex formulas to keep it from recalculating at every change they make.

Comment: Its worth pointing out that if you open multiple spreadsheets, only one has to be set to manual for all of them to be like that.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, we have files over the network drive. The calculation turned to "Manual" only in case where there was a  **"Circular reference"** by mistake in my file. That's the only reason the calculation went to manual.